# setting up Django app to work on google app engine GAE (app.yaml & main.py)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, pycharm

I have a working Django app that I was able to get functioning on Heroku. The structure is project named 'untitled' and an app named 'web' such that the structure is:

project_root

static

templates

untitled

--->**init**.py

--->settings.py

--->urls.py

--->wsgi.py

web

--->**init**.py

--->admin.py

--->apps.py

--->models.py

--->tests.py

--->urls.py

--->views.py

This is a fairly basic app that I can get working outside of GAE (local and on Heroku), however, I'm getting stuck on the app.yaml and main.py requirements for GAE.

My app.yaml is:

```
application: seismic-interpretation-institute-py27
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "latest"
```

and my main.py (generated from PyCharm) is

```
import os,sys

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import django.core.signals
import django.db
import django.dispatch.dispatcher

# Google App Engine imports.
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

# Force Django to reload its settings.
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'untitled.settings'

# Unregister the rollback event handler.
django.dispatch.dispatcher.disconnect(
  django.db._rollback_on_exception,
  django.core.signals.got_request_exception)


def main():
    # Create a Django application for WSGI.
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

    # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Finally, the output that is reported when running locally is

[image]

It seems that the error,

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

is causing my problems. I am not exactly sure how to fix it.

Comment: For anyone interested, I used Bear Brown's comment to realize that I edited the default PyCharm main.py file. I seemed to have moved the `import os,sys` and the `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'untitled.settings` to the first two line of the main.py file listed above. This cleared up the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace

```
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'untitled.settings'
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "untitled.settings")
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! That fixed it.